# Save current user session in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, session, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I am developing windows phone app. It require user to login.
I trying to save the current user session after login successful in windows phone app.

I am using `IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings` to save the current user session.

Here is code

```
            LoginDO objLoginDO = default(LoginDO);
            if (dtbUserDetails != null)
            {
                objLoginDO = new LoginDO(dtbUserDetails.UserID,
                                         dtbUserDetails.FirstName,
                                         dtbUserDetails.LastName,
                                         dtbUserDetails.UserName,
                                         dtbUserDetails.DisplayName,
                                         Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2010"),
                                         "","", Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now),
                                         dtbUserDetails.MobileNumber,
                                         dtbUserDetails.Location);

                UserControlBaseClass u = new UserControlBaseClass();
                //PhoneApplicationService.Current.State[u.LOGIN_DO] = objLoginDO;
                IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;                    
                settings[u.LOGIN_DO] = objLoginDO;
                settings.Save();
             }
```

Here I am getting the error when complier reach to `settings.Save()`

**Error**

> Type 'Demo.Classes.LoginDO' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. Alternatively, you can ensure that the type is public and has a parameterless constructor - all public members of the type will then be serialized, and no attributes will be required.

I am not getting why this error I am getting? can some one help me to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When saving in the application settings, it is using a DataContractSerialiser to serialize your object, the problem is probably that you didn't define a parameter less constructor which is required by the DataContractSerializer. Just add one and that you solve your problem.

Comment: Is it necessary to define parameter less constructor.

Comment: I have just removed the parameter from constructor. and my problem is solved.

Comment: If you don't want to have a parameterless contructor then you can either serialise the class yourself to a string and save the string into the AppSettings or add the DataContract attribute on your class and DataMember on each property

Comment: When my deactivate the session value get's cleared. When I log in to app I pressed home key of emulator and after that I again start my app, so that time I am not able to redirect to my home page. It will again ask for username and password.

Comment: PhoneApplicationService.Current.State will be cleared when you restart the app but not IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.

Comment: I have used `IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings` but it is clearing

Comment: Could you check that you don't see any error on startup in the console (maybe it fail to deserialise silently). Did you set DataContract on the class? If you did then you need to set DataMember on each property you want saved. If you didn't set DataContract on the class everything you want saved need to be a public property. Otherwise you can try to see what is saved in the settings file using the command line tool ISETool.exe or  with IsoStorage  spy (http://isostorespy.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Hello, I want to ask one thing. Can we save the bitmapimage in IsolatedStorageSettings ?

Comment: No, BitmapImage are not serializable so they cannot be saved in IsolatedStorageSettings. You could load the BitmapImage into a WriteableBitmap and save the byte array into the IsolatedStorageSettings but I advice against it. I think it would be better to save the image in isolated storage independently and just have a link to it in the settings. If you have a lot of large object in IsolatedStorageSettings (all the settings are saved in a single file), when you first access the IsolatedStorageSettings it will freeze your UI since it will take longer to load.